# Meaning of the univalence axiom on plain data types

Tags: homotopy-type-theory

I'm trying to wrap my head around HoTT and can't figure out the intuitive meaning and validity of the univalence axiom.  IIUC this axiom says:

```
UA: ∀ A,B:Type . (A = B) ≃ (A ≃ B)
```

where `X ≃ Y` is a shorthand for `(X → Y) ∧ (Y → X)`.

When I take A and B to be propositions, this makes a lot of sense: it basically gives my that two equivalent propositions can be considered as equal, and given some form of proof irrelevance it makes perfect sense.

But how can it make sense when A and B are, say `nat` and `bool`, for example?  I can trivially define a function of type `nat → bool` as well as a function of type `bool → nat`, yet it doesn't make sense to me to state that `nat = bool`.  So is there some detail of the definition of UA that prevents its use on things like nat/bool, or does it really also apply in this case, in which case does it mean that the usual understanding of the `refl` elimination needs to be refined so it's not just a sort of type-cast any more but has potentially non-trivial computational content?

Comment: Your definition of `X ≃ Y` is wrong, see the [correct definition](https://github.com/HoTT/HoTT-Agda/blob/master/lib/Equivalences.agda#L79).

Comment: Aha!  Thank you, Andrej.  That all makes a lot more sense now.